# Google Analytics - Download link event tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events

I would like to count my downloads through Google Analytics events. Unfortunately nothing shows up in my statistics.
This is the GA code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

And my link:

```
<a href="advanced-pack.zip" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'Pack', 'Advanced']);">Download</a>
```

Why it is not working?

Comment: It usually takes 24 hour to reflect in the report. How long has it been since you updated the google analytics in your site?

Comment: It has been over 4 days.

Comment: I think the problem would be that the link href is getting called before the javascript has a chance to trigger.  Note in the google example of how to build these links the href is "#" and as such does not take you to another page before the javascript is executed.

Comment: A much better explanation here: http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `Google Documentations` :

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/files/map.pdf" onClick="javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/downloads/map']);">
```

To verify that _trackPageview is being called correctly, you can check your Top Content report 24-48 hours after the updated tracking code has been executed. You should be able to see the assigned pagename in your report.

Comment: Is it not recommended to use **Events**? I need to generate **Goals** and **Conversion Rate** out of it through Google Analytics.